# CKEDITOR link focus bug vue/vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, vuetify.js

I am running into an issue with trying to use the CKEDITOR link button when another input field is present.

```
<v-text-field
  name="editSubject"
  :label="$t('email.form.subject')"
  value=""
  v-model="editEmailSubject"
></v-text-field>

<label class="caption grey--text">{{$t('email.form.content')}}</label>
<div class="note-ck-editor">
  <ckeditor
     :editor="editor"
     tag-name="textarea"
     v-model="editEmailText"
     :config="editorConfig"
  ></ckeditor>
</div>
```

When I click the link button the  [auto focus goes to the v-text-field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3BTf.png) instead of the newly opened dialog to add a hyperlink.

Removing the v-text-field or simply moving below the ckeditor solves the problem however as this is for an email dialog I need the text-field above the editor

Answer (score 3):

Actually this solution isn't from me, I stumbled upon it by facing the same problem.

Vuetify Dialog steals Focus from rest so Use this Code in v-dialog

```
:retain-focus="false"
```

and the fields and dialog and text fields will not steal the focus within Dialog.

and if you are not able to see you balloon toolbar. Use below CSS in your main CSS file and import it in your App.js.

```
body {
  /* We need to assaign this CSS Custom property to the body instead of :root, because of CSS Specificity and codepen stylesheet placement before loaded CKE5 content. */
  --ck-z-default: 3100;
  --ck-z-modal: calc( var(--ck-z-default) + 3999 );
}
```

above is specified only for Vue/Vuetify. hope it solves your problem as well.

Comment: working well, should be markes as the answer